# How to update nested map at non-existent path

Tags: elixir

There are the Kernel functions for updating nested data structures in Elixir, Kernel.put_in/3 and Kernel.update_in/3, which help update Elixir's immutable data structures using a path and a value, or a function, in the latter case.

This is the example from the documentation for `update_in`:

```
users = %{"john" => %{age: 27}, "meg" => %{age: 23}}
update_in(users, ["john", :age], &(&1 + 1))
%{"john" => %{age: 28}, "meg" => %{age: 23}}
```

How would this need to change to support placing values at a non-existent path in the data structure?

This is what happens in case an unknown first path element is used:

```
put_in(users, ["clara", :age], 29)
** (ArgumentError) could not put/update key :age on a nil value
    (elixir) lib/access.ex:379: Access.get_and_update/3
    (elixir) lib/map.ex:773: Map.get_and_update/3
    (elixir) lib/kernel.ex:2057: Kernel.put_in/3
```

The desired result would be this:

```
%{"john" => %{age: 27}, "meg" => %{age: 23}, "clara" => %{age: 29}}
```

Comment: An alternate option would be to use [`Iteraptor.bury/4`](https://hexdocs.pm/iteraptor/Iteraptor.Extras.html#bury/4) from [`Iteraptor`](https://github.com/am-kantox/elixir-iteraptor) package designed explicitly for this and similar purposes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `Access.key/2` to specify a default value for a specific key if it's not present. In this case, you need to default the value of the key `"clara"` to `%{}`:

```
iex(1)> users = %{"john" => %{age: 27}, "meg" => %{age: 23}}
iex(2)> put_in(users, [Access.key("clara", %{}), :age], 29)
%{"clara" => %{age: 29}, "john" => %{age: 27}, "meg" => %{age: 23}}
```